# Understanding "self.head" in singly linked-list

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to practice implementing LinkedLists, and for some reason cannot wrap my head fully around the concept of "self.head." The first version of the function below does not work, yet simply storing "self.head" in "n" -- but only after the else clause? -- causes it to work. Shouldn't these functions be functionally identical?

I thought "self.head" simply refers to where you are whilst traversing the list, so what is the difference between saying: "Self.head is the current node, so self.head.next is the next node" and "n = self.head. N is the current node, so n.next is the next node"?

```
# Doesn't work:

def append(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new_node
    else:
        while self.head.next is not None:
            self.head = self.head.next
        self.head.next = new_node


# Works:

def append(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new_node
    else:
        n = self.head
        while n.next is not None:
            n = n.next
        n.ref = new_node
```

Comment: The first function changes what `head` is pointing/referring to. While the second one copies the 'reference' of head to `n` and moves `n` instead of `head`. So in short, the first function uses `head` as the current node (the node that moves) while the second function uses `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version, you are actually moving the 'head' which should not be done because 'head' should always be pointing to the first node in case of a linked list. Also while doing so, you are actually loosing the previous nodes. Let's run a simple scenario using the first version of your function.
Let's suppose you have added three values to your linked list: 2,3,4 so the 'append' function should be called three times:

**append(2):**
'if' condition will be true, *'self.head' will point to '2'* and self.head.next will be 'None'. So just to say, our linked_list at the moment will be:
'2 -> None'

**append(3):**
*self.head will still point to '2'* but in this case, the code inside else will be executed but while loop will not be executed as 'self.head.next' is 'None' actually. So the new node will be added and our linked list will become:
'2 -> 3 -> None' *Note that 'self.head' is still haven't moved to the next node.

**append(4):**
Now here, inside the else clause, while loop will be executed, 'self.head' will be pointing to '3' after executing 'self.head = self.head.next' and as soon as there will be no reference to the first node(2), as we have moved the head to the next node, that node will be lost(not accessible) and after appending 4, your linked list at the end will be actually:
3 -> 4 -> None with 'self.head' pointing to '3' now.
You should remember that in Python, [An object stays alive, as long as there is at least one reference to it](https://realpython.com/python-variables/). Your first version of the append function is actually loosing that reference to the head node each time a node is added after the second node.